# Understanding assignments and "extends" in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm taking a beginners java course online, and I need to better understand how the assignments work with inheritance.
If I have, for example, these classes...

```
public class Cell{...}
public class BloodCell extends Cell {...}
public class RedBloodCell extends BloodCell {...}
```

Are these valid?

```
Cell c = new BloodCell();
Cell c = new RedBloodCell();
BloodCell c = new RedBloodCell();
RedBloodCell c = new BloodCell();
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html Indicate what is unclear in the documentation by quoting it and stating precisely what problem you face.

Comment: All are valid but the final one. (Because a `BloodCell` is *not* a `RedBloodCell`.) It might be better to ask *why* they're valid, if you have concerns/questions, as opposed to whether they *are*, which as others are mentioning can be checked by the compiler.

Comment: You could also compile the code, and see if it causes compilation errors.

Comment: We make a poor substitute for your trusty Java compiler.

Comment: When learning to program, step one is setting up your development environment. Don't learn by pen and paper.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It didn't really talk about assignment, as far as I could see, not in the way my question does.

Comment: @CraigOtis Thank you. and from now on, I think I will use the compiler to check these things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extends
```

is used for inheritance and in layman term it resembles "is-a" property

So class A which extends some other class B, means that "Class A is-a Class B".
And in other words Class B is a Parent of Class A.

Parent class reference can hold a child object but vice-versa is not possible.

```
Cell c = new BloodCell();   // OK, as BloodCell is a Cell,
Cell c = new RedBloodCell();   // OK, RedBloodCell is a Cell
BloodCell c = new RedBloodCell();   // OK, RedBloodCell is a BloodCell
RedBloodCell c = new BloodCell();  // ERROR, BloodCell is not a RedBloodCell
```

Comment: Please accpt the answer, if you like it by clicking on the "tick sign"

Answer (score 0):

```
Cell c = new BloodCell(); //OK: all blood cells are cells
Cell c = new RedBloodCell();//OK: all red blood cells are cells
BloodCell c = new RedBloodCell();//OK: all red blood cells are blood cells
RedBloodCell c = new BloodCell();//ERROR: not all blood cells are red blood cells
```